# Prove $|\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt|\le \int_{a}^{b}|f(t)|dt$ complex

Tags: complex-analysis

$|\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt|\le \int_{a}^{b}|f(t)|dt$

For demonstration used in the book Ahlfors (of complex variable) the following:
$$Re\left[e^{-i\theta}\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt\right]=\left|\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt\right|$$
For $\theta=arg\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt$

Could you help me understand this step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\theta$ is such that $\int_a^bf(t)dt=re^{i\theta}$ where $r=|\int_a^bf(x)dt|$. This implies
$$
\text{Re}\left[e^{-i\theta}\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt\right]=\text{Re}\left[e^{-i\theta}re^{i\theta}\right]=\text{Re}[r]=r=\left|\int_a^bf(x)dt\right|.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt = z = re^{i\theta} \rightarrow e^{-i\theta}z = \frac{1}{r} \bar{z} z = r = \left|\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt\right| 
$$